# Is an Email response considered an official document?

Tags: air-travel, germany, airlines, officials

Can an email response, e.g. from the German Auswärtiges Amt, be considered an official document and used during travel?

As an example: If I have an electronic response stating that no special authorisation (Reisevollmacht) is needed for immigration or travel, can I use this if the airline asks me to show them a special authorisation (Reisevollmacht)

Comment: Generally no. Anyone can spoof an email, it's trivially simple.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: But what's an official document in this context? You can always try and anything can help sway the airlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Reisevollmacht is a document confirming that a minor may travel with an adult who is not the legal guardian. As Roddy explained in his comment, an email cannot possibly *replace* a Reisevollmacht if you should really need one. It might be helpful to convince the airline that no Reisevollmacht is necessary in your case.

If the email explains why no Reisevollmacht is necessary in your case, with a reference to the applicable laws, then having it along should help the airline staff to look things up, as explained by Relaxed. If it simply says "not necessary" without further explanation, it is useless for your purposes.

Also, an airline *may* have internal guidelines which go beyond those required by law, and make them part of the fine print in your contract. Then the email won't help, either.